# mysql_error() returning 'No such file or directory' in php run via unix terminal

Tags: mysql, unix, error-handling, php

I'm working through this tutorial on php development via the command line (I'm using a unix prompt on a mac). I have the code below in a file titled test.php.

```
<?php

define ('DB_CONNECTION_FAILED',1);

if ( !@mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') ) {

fwrite(STDERR,mysql_error()."\n");
}

exit(0);

?>
```

When I run it in the terminal using the command:

```
php test.php
```

It returns:

```
No such file or directory
```

When I run the code below in a browser:

```
<?php

define ('DB_CONNECTION_FAILED',1);

if ( !@mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') ) {
echo mysql_error();
}

exit(0);

?>
```

I get the expected error:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure your connecting authorization parameters are correct?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Show result of `php --version` please.

Comment: Here is php --version: PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 14:49:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Comment: try `file_put_contents('php://stderr', mysql_error()."\n");`

Comment: @AndreyVolk your code gets rid of the error but all I get in the terminal are a couple blank lines.

Comment: Not sure what you try to do. Why stderr?

Comment: Works fine for me with `PHP 5.4.13 (cli)` on Fedora 18 x86_64. /check `man php`. Maybe you need to call this with `php -f test.php` or some other argument like that. Also, it might be a SELinux thing (I don't know if Mac has something like that), so check your SE logs or try running a permissive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check your *mysql.default_socket* set in php is similar to socket made by mysql